# How to make this Breadcrumb Schema Generator work properly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a schema generator which will work something like this:

https://wtools.io/breadcrumb-json-ld-schema-generator

But the problem is i am able to add values and generate the schema list items but everytime i click "click me" a value is added to the schema as ListItem which is clearly not the intended behavior. Also, am failing to remove any added item from the generated schema even when i remove it from the list above.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background: silver;
        }

        .dis {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <label for="item">Add an item: </label>
        <input id="item" type="text" size="20"><br>
        <input id="url" type="url" size="20"><br>
        <input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Add!">
    </form>
    <ul id="ul">
    </ul>
    <p> Click an item to remove it from the list. </p>
    <button onclick="myFunction();">Click me</button>
    <br><br> &#x3C;script type=&#x22;application/ld+json&#x22;&#x3E;<br>
    <div class="output">{ &#x22;@context&#x22;: &#x22;https://schema.org&#x22;, &#x22;@type&#x22;: &#x22;BreadcrumbList&#x22;, &#x22;itemListElement&#x22;: [ { &#x22;@type&#x22;: &#x22;ListItem&#x22;, &#x22;position&#x22;: 1, &#x22;name&#x22;: &#x22;Google&#x22;, &#x22;item&#x22;: &#x22;google.com&#x22; } ] }</div>&#x3C;/script&#x3E;
</body>

</html>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
    button.onclick = addItem;
}

function addItem() {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("item"); //getting text input
    var text = textInput.value; //getting value of text input element
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul"); //getting element <ul> to add element to
    var li = document.createElement("li"); //creating li element to add
    li.setAttribute("class", "breadcrumb-item");
    li.innerHTML = text; //inserting text into newly created <li> element
    li.onclick = function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);
    }
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
//script generation code here 
// Create Script
var el = document.createElement('script');
el.type = 'application/ld+json';
// Set initial position
var position = 0;
// Create breadcrumb object
var breadcrumb = {
    position: 0,
    name: "",
    item: ""
}
// Empty array for list items
var listArray = []

function myFunction() {
    // Loop through each breadcrumb link and set attributes
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb-item');
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        var newItem = Object.create(breadcrumb);
        var curItem = items[i];
        newItem["@type"] = "ListItem";
        position++;
        newItem.position = position;
        newItem.name = document.getElementById("item").value;
        newItem.item = document.getElementById("url").value;
        listArray.push(newItem);
    }
    // Create overarching Schema object
    var breadcrumbSchema = {
        "@context": "https://schema.org/",
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": listArray
    };
    var finalSchema = JSON.stringify(breadcrumbSchema);
    // Add schema to Script
    el.text = finalSchema;
    // Set head variable with browser fallback
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    // Testing purposes - Show example of string in HTML
    document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = finalSchema;
    // This won't work in codepen
    head.appendChild(el);
    // Testing purposes - Inspect source to see script generated inside of the "output" div
    document.querySelector('.output').appendChild(el);
}
```

This is my first time working with JS so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the function to remove an item from your unordered list try adding a call to remove it from the listArray.

```
let textInput = document.getElementById("item");  //getting text input
let text = textInput.value;   //getting value of text input element
let ul = document.getElementById("ul");  //getting element <ul> to add element to
let li = document.createElement("li");  //creating li element to add
li.setAttribute("class", "breadcrumb-item");
li.innerHTML = text;    //inserting text into newly created <li> element
li.onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);  
    //call to remove from listArray goes here
    setTimeout(function() {   
 }, 1000);
}
ul.appendChild(li);
```

It might look like:

```
function removefromlist(item_position)
{
   for(l in listArray){
       if(listArray[1].position == item_position){
           listArray.splice(l,1);
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

Unless I'm missing something I'm not sure what other type would be added to your schema, because on line 92 of your code "ListItem" is the only type you ever assign.